# Excessive memory usage with multiprocessing pool

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to output each entry in a dictionary to a JSON file using multiprocessing in Python 3.6. Here is the code:

```
def export_json(t):
    path = os.path.join(t[2], t[0] + '.json')
    with open(path, 'w') as json_file:
        json.dump(t[1], json_file, indent = 4)

class TrackExportHelper():

    def execute(self):
        pool = Pool(processes = self.num_threads)
        pool.map(export_json, self.enumerate())

    def enumerate(self):
        for track in self.tracks:
            yield (track, copy.deepcopy(self.tracks[track]), self.output_dir)
```

This is a small part of a large codebase but the `self.tracks` is basically the only data object in the program and is loaded from a large JSON file and processed before we get to this stage. The memory usage is around 34GB before calling `execute`. However with a pool of 12 processes, the memory usage reaches 160GB. Commenting out the actual `json.dump` line does't seem to affect the memory usage.

Is this amount of overhead reasonable? I was expecting at most twice the memory usage of the original data with some minor overhead as each top-level dictionary is copied once, however removing the `deepcopy` reduces the memory usage only marginally (I mainly added the `deepcopy` to avoid unnecessary memory usage due to copy-on-write complications due to reference counting, but doesn't seem to help).

How can I reduce this overhead while still parallelizing this stage?